# Error when executing success post condition: hudson.AbortException: No test report files were found. Configuration error?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

We are facing this problem. Below is the error log. This job is running on AWS containers and will not be having a permanent workspace to check and see the reports folder. Can any of you please help in resolving this issue? It is a pipeline job and looking for a solution to fix this issue.

```
[Pipeline] junit
Error when executing success post condition:
hudson.AbortException: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
```

This is the pipeline script and have included junit in the script with the path but still the error remains.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably a logic error in your pipeline. The following  pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Build'
            }
    }
    }
    post {
        always {
            junit 'junit.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the same error:

```
Recording test results
No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Error when executing always post condition:
hudson.AbortException: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
```

Because the build stage doesn't produce a junit.xml file and the post section will always expect it to be there.

Have a look at your pipeline and make sure you always produce junit test result xmls, or conditionalize the junit step.